# Python: using ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to use Dll from python using ctypes but I read the tutorial and I don´t understand anything!!

I wants to load the dll from path and access to its functions...

SOS!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
import ctypes
foo = ctypes.CDLL("/path/to/library")
foo.function_name()
```

You should maybe look for a better tutorial. Here is one: http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html

Comment: Ok Thanks I try it again.

But now, what can I use *.lib with python?? The code isn´t the same no?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: yes, sorry my english is horrible!!

I´ve 2 problems:

->I try to load dll with this code:
f = ctypes.CDLL("vix.dll")

and it returns can find the specific module...

->I need add use in python script functions contained in "AllProducts.lib"